# "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" when selecting text

Tags: ios, swift, tttattributedlabel

I am trying to select and than copy text displayed using the [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) library. I created the CopyableLabel class to make the TTTAttributedLabel copyable, like when you want to make a UILabel copyable. This works fine but it do not allow to select a portion/part of text but it copy the hole text. I tried to implement the select or selectselectAll action in canPerformAction to then try to highlight to desired portion of text to copy:

```
    class CopyableLabel :TTTAttributedLabel {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: (Any)?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy)
    }

    func select() {
        becomeFirstResponder()
        let menu = UIMenuController.shared
        if !menu.isMenuVisible {
            menu.setTargetRect(bounds, in: self)
            menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
        }
    }



    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender:  Any?) -> Bool {

            if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy) {
                return true
            }else if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)){
                return true
            }

            return false
        }
    }
```

When I click on the select All menu, the app crashes with the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: CopiableLabel selectAll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Could you show the whole error message? Usually the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" errors state the method and class object that may help debugging...

Comment: Same error with this code too